# Forward inside Service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, service, containers, forward

I want to use the `forward()` method inside of a service. I defined `http_kernel` as argument for my service but I get this error :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method forward()
```

config.yml :

```
 my.service:
     class: MyProject\MyBundle\MyService
     arguments: 
        http_kernel: "@http_kernel"
```

MyService.php :

```
public function __construct($http_kernel) {
    $this->http_kernel = $http_kernel;
    $response = $this->http_kernel->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
        'name'  => $name,
         'color' => 'green',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Forward is for controllers, if you want access to the forward method, I believe you'll need to extend the Symfony Controller class.

Comment: If this service is called by your current controller, then this would return a response that you'd check inside your current controller and then forward to another controller.

Comment: Are you sure that you need forward request? Redirect is not enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.html) object has no method `forward`. It's a method of [`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_forward)
This is why you are getting this error.
As a side note, you should not do any computation into your constructor. Better create a `process` method which is called immediatly after.

Here's another way to do this:

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    my.service:
        class: MyProject\MyBundle\MyService
        scope: request
        arguments:
            - @http_kernel
            - @request
        calls:
            - [ handleForward, [] ]
```

**Note**: `scope: request` is a mandatory parameter in order to give the `@request` service to your object.

<kbd>**MyProject\MyBundle\MyService**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyService
{
    protected $request;
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $kernel, Request $request)
    {
        $this->kernel  = $kernel;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function handleForward()
    {
        $controller = 'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy';
        $path = array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'color' => 'green',
            '_controller' => $controller
        );
        $subRequest = $this->request->duplicate(array(), null, $path);

        $response = $this->kernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by injecting container into your service and then add forward function like below.

**services.yml**

```
 my.service:
     class: MyProject\MyBundle\MyService
     arguments: ['@service_container']
```

**MyService.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $container;

    function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;     
    }

    public function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
    {
        $path['_controller'] = $controller;
        $subRequest = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->duplicate($query, null, $path);

        return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
    }

    function yourFunction(){
        $response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'color' => 'green',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution almost works for me. But I'm retrieving the data by `$request->request->all()` and it displays blank. Don't know where the problem is...

Comment: how are you getting `$request` variable? could you show me that code. Because you cannot use `Request $request` in services.

Comment: I've done all the things same as above and trying to retrieve the passed array from the controller through `Request $request` but it gives me null...